# How to take screenshot of failed test in selenium webdriver using ReportNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If anyone know how to take screenshot of failed test/methods in selenium webdriver using reportNG then please help.

If you provide code then its helpfull or provide some ideas to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you supply the nonworking code and a detailed description what exactly "is not working"? Otherwise it's not that easy to help.

Comment: @Frank if you know code then share it and help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.

```
WebDriver firfoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
firfoxDriver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
File file = ((TakesScreenshot)firfoxDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("E:\\Data\\ss.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use this:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void catchExceptions(ITestResult result){
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
String methodName = result.getName();
if(!result.isSuccess()){
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File((String)     PathConverter.convert("failure_screenshots/"+methodName+"_"+formater.format(calendar.getTime())+".png")));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well It's depend on your framework that where the control is going after failing the method.

Suppose in your case it is going in catch exception block then copy that code in catch block.

```
File file = ((TakesScreenshot)firfoxDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("YOUR PATH"+Filename+.JPG));
```

Comment: Screenshot problem resolved but now I want to add failed method screenshot in report generated by ReportNG...That means in HTML report

Comment: Yes, Means we make report in testNG and we have option in TestNG to make Self configurable HTML format reports with the help of ReportNG jar file..

Comment: For that you need override onTestFailure method of Testng and then you need to add that class to listeners in testng.xml .. For more details :- http://www.automationtesting.co.in/2010/07/testng-take-screenshot-of-failed-test.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Itestlistener` in `testng` to take screenshot. `testng` has an in built function by which you can take screenshot when it fails.

Just create a seperate listerner class and paste this code:

```
public class listeners implements ITestListener{

//This "Base " is the main class where you can pass the result of test case and write the //code for screenshot  
//I cam creating an object so I can access the method that I created for screenshot in this base class.  
//I am also getting the result name so I can identify which test case it got failed


Base b = new Base();
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) { 
    try {
        //Getting the result name by result.getName() method         
        b.getScreenshot( result.getName());
        System.out.println("The Failed test is=="+result.getName());
    }   
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}   
}
```

I created this `getScreenshot` method in the base class and passing the result name

```
public class Base {

public WebDriver InitializeDr() throws IOException {  
    //Creating the method to take screenshot in the Base class    
    public void getScreenshot(String result) throws IOException
    {  
        File dest=new File("D:\\Work\\KT\\Scr Shot\\"+result+"test.png");  
        File src=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest);  
    }  
}  
}
```